# Detect Arabic language using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to detect Arabic language when typed in a Textbox using a Javascript??
Is there any way to do this.

I want to do a system where the system automatically detects the Arabic Language written in the textbox of the Webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the list of [Unicode characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Arabic) it seems you need to check symbols in the unicode range `U+0600-U+06FF`. So if a user enters one of those symbols inside the textbox you could detect the Arabic language. Also note that there're many unicode ranges you may want to allow. Beside Arabic (0600—06FF, 225 characters) you have

- Arabic Supplement (0750—077F, 48 characters)
- Arabic Extended-A (08A0—08FF, 39 characters)
- Arabic Presentation Forms-A (FB50—FDFF, 608 characters)
- Arabic Presentation Forms-B (FE70—FEFF, 140 characters)
- Rumi Numeral Symbols (10E60—10E7F, 31 characters)
- Arabic Mathematical Alphabetic Symbols (1EE00—1EEFF, 143 characters)

Answer (score 0):

Try This: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301832/Custom-Text-box-Control-that-Switch-keyboard-langu